# How to display a div background in a web browser control in compact cf c#

Tags: c#, compact-framework, webbrowser-control

I am using the web browser control embedded into my compact cf c# application.  I have this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="background-image: url('sprite2.png'); width: 291px; height: 176px;" />
</body>
</html>
```

If use a normal web app on my PC the image appears.  If I use it in compact cf it does not. The image is definatley on the device. Does this limited edition of the web browser control support background image and if so how can i get it to use a local file?

Thanks

Comment: **What version of the [CF] are you working with?** If CF 3.5 or earlier, you have IE4 on your device. Is a `PNG` image supported in IE4?  What about `<div>` tags? Were those around during IE4? If so, were all of those **styles** supported?

Comment: @jp2code Hi, i am using CF2.0. I should have worded my question better as I had also opened a website in IE on the device that successfully loads a div and its image from my server. My specific need is how to view a local image file on the device. The div is not the issue. .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get sprites to work on my emulator (do not currently have a device to test on).

[image: CEZoom]

My background image did not show, but the sprites I use for my menu item do appear.

Obviously, Hover does not work (since there is no mouse to hover over the links).

Is your device able to reach other sites online?

Comment: HI, thanks for replying. The sprites I use are say 10 frames by 10 frames so a total of 100 frames. So, reading left to right and going down each row I am able to simulate a video clip. To do this I used JavaScript which i think would not work on IE4 unfortunately...

Comment: Can you load the page shown in the pic above? It uses a sprite for the menu control, but I only use up and down. The colors should change depending on what page of the menu the person is in. If it works, I can post the code.